# Having troubles with unRarX

Tags: macos, mac, rar

I downloaded unRarX and whenever I try to open a .Rar file (video), it does this and does not play the video:

UNRAR 3.60 beta 6 freeware Copyright (c) 1993-2006 Alexander Roshal

Extracting from /Users/[username]/Downloads/HomScPermacult.rar

Extracting /Users/[username]/Downloads/Gaia's Garden - A Guide to Home-Scale Permaculture.pdf  0% 1% 2% 3% 4% 5% 6% 7% 8% 9% 10% 11% 12% 13% 14% 15% 16% 17% 18% 19% 20% 21% 22% 23% 24% 25% 26% 27% 28% 29% 30% 31% 32% 33% 34% 35% 36% 37% 38% 39% 40% 41% 42% 43% 44% 45% 46% 47% 48% 49% 50% 51% 52% 53% 54% 55% 56% 57% 58% 59% 60% 61% 62% 63% 64% 65% 66% 67% 68% 69% 70% 71% 72% 73% 74% 75% 76% 77% 78% 79% 80% 81% 82% 83% 84% 85% 86% 87% 88% 89% 90% 91% 92% 93% 94% 95% 96% 97% 98% 99% OK 
Extracting /Users/[username]/Downloads/hotfile.txt 
 99% OK 
All OK

Comment: You've asked many questions, you should go back and mark some of them as accepted.

Comment: davr, i didn't know i could do that; how do u do it?

Comment: You hit the checkmark under the answer you like the best.

Answer (score 4):

UnrarX is just a soft to decompress the video, you still need to play it with Quicktime or another video player and you still need to have the right plugin for your video player.

EDIT : The file you're unraring is NOT a video, it's a PDF. Open it with Preview, that's all.